# How to tidy raw code from node_modules to readable format - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have to refer to files in node modules frequently, but sometimes they are compressed to a single line of code and make them unreadable. My prettier formatter doesn't format these files. Is there a way I can tidy the raw code to a readable format like regular js files?
[image]

Comment: Often you can find the github page on NPM which will contain the uncompressed code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions for this.

---

The first solution is to configure one of Prettier's settings.

One of Prettier's settings is for formatting the `node_modules` directory. To change it, follow the steps below.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) to open up the Settings page in Visual Studio Code.
2. Search *Prettier* in the search box. Then, scroll all the way to the bottom of the Settings page.
3. Check the *With Node Modules* setting. This will process files in the `node_modules` folder.

   [image: Prettier Settings]

Now, when you go back to your minified file in `node_modules`, it should be formatted.

If the file isn't yet formatted, then right-click, and click *Format Document*. This should format the file with Prettier.

**Warning:** If your computer doesn't have a lot of processing power (RAM), then the formatting process may make your computer lag.

---

The second solution possible is to go onto your repository's GitHub page, and see the uncompressed code from there.

You can access this page from [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/), or [github.com](https://github.com/).

---

In conclusion, you can format the code in `node_modules` with Prettier, or you can see the uncompressed code online on a code hosting service (e.g. GitHub).